# Lazy initialisation of lazy_static?

Tags: rust, option-type, lazy-initialization, lazy-static

I've already had some success with `lazy_static`:

```
static ref WORD_COUNT_REPORTING_STEP_MUTEX: Arc<Mutex<usize>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
static ref INDEX_NAME: RwLock<String> = RwLock::new("".to_string());
static ref LANGUAGE_DETECTOR: LanguageDetector = LanguageDetectorBuilder::from_all_languages().with_preloaded_language_models().build();
```

But I'm really scratching my head over what should seemingly be a fairly easy pattern: set something of type `Option<T>` to `None` and then initialise on discovering that that `Option` is indeed `None`. If it is discovered that the `Option` is `Some`, skip the initialisation. After the initialisation block, get the `Option` and `unwrap()`.

NB the type here is `reqwest::blocking::client::Client`.

So far I've got:

```
lazy_static! {
    static ref REQWEST_CLIENT_OPTION: Option<Client> = None;
}
```

Then, in a function:

```
...
match &*REQWEST_CLIENT_OPTION {
    Some(reqwest_client) => {
        info!("reqwest_client_option currently non-None");
    },
    None => {
        info!("reqwest_client_option currently None");
        
        // configuration and build of the client
        let es_path = r#"D:\apps\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-8.6.2\config"#;
        set_var("ES_PATH_CONF", &es_path); // from crate tmp_env
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        let cert_path = format!(r#"{es_path}\certs\http_ca.crt"#);
        let mut cert_file = File::open(cert_path).expect("problem opening certificate file");
        cert_file.read_to_end(&mut buf).ok();
        let cert = reqwest::Certificate::from_pem(&buf).expect("problem generating certificate"); // delivers cert OK
        let reqwest_client = Client::builder()
            .add_root_certificate(cert)
            .timeout(std::time::Duration::from_millis(5_000))
            .build().expect("problem building the request client");

        // now I try to set the Option...
        let mut static_client = &*REQWEST_CLIENT_OPTION;
        info!("static_client type {}", utilities::str_type_of(&static_client));
        // static_client type &core::option::Option<reqwest::blocking::client::Client>
        static_client = &Some(reqwest_client)
        // not now possible to check static_client. 
    }
}
let reqwest_client = REQWEST_CLIENT_OPTION.as_ref().unwrap();    
...
```

The above is largely guesswork. Needless to say, I've tried innumerable permutations involving *, & and things like `let_mut`. I hoped this might work:

```
*static_client = Some(reqwest_client);
```

... but this fails: " ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `static_client` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be written".

At least the above code compiles OK.
The line "reqwest_client_option currently None" is printed.
But to my disappointment the last line causes a panic:

```
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value
```

NB I also tried a variant with `if let Some(reqwest_client) ...` but ran into the same sorts of problems. This construction would probably be more elegant.

Comment: You maybe are looking for [`OnceCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html)

Comment: Also, [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) has a neat API.

Comment: And you should avoid `lazy_static` for new projects anyway, use `once_cell` instead.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Care to say why? PeterHall's solution is obviously the tool for the job. Has `lazy_static` fallen into disfavour?

Comment: I think this is simply "you don't need it, `once_cell` has all of its capabilities and more".

Comment: And it doesn't use macros, and it's being incorporated into std, so when time comes you can just remove the crate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`OnceCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html) or, since you are making it static, [`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html).

For example:

```
use std::sync::OnceLock;
use reqwest::blocking::Client;

static REQWEST_CLIENT: OnceLock<Client> = OnceLock::new();

fn main(){
    let client = REQWEST_CLIENT.get_or_init(|| {
        Client::builder()
            // other options
            .build()
            .expect("problem building the reqwest client")
    });

    // use client
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works well. This is obviously the best tool for the job, but I'm also just wondering whether what I was trying to do with a `lazy_static` and a `ref` can work. Now I see that ChayimFriedman has said "don't use lazy_static"... but not why. Is it on the way to deprecation or something?